# Python: How can I extract common setup code into a single file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, initialization

I have a few Python scripts that use the same configs and variable initialization. How would I extract this common code out into a single file to be included everywhere? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do is:

1 - Store all the config settings within a text file (such as a config.json)

2 - Create a `class Config` which loads the json file(s) and provides useful methods to load and read the configs, perform some concatenations, or simply returns it as a dict

4 - I ensure I do not load the config(s) multiple times (goal: single disk read and config caching) by using a module `Globals` (which is just an empty Global.py file) in which I store the dict and controls if it exists before deciding to load the config.

3 - `import Config`, do a `config = Config()` and I am good to go

Comment: Couldn't you completely skip the json file and just store the settings directly as members in the class?

Comment: You could, but decorrelating your configuration from your code is better. You can easily save/import from a NoSQL DB, or any remote API. Also it allows devs teams to work on it without risking damaging the code. JSON is also interoperable on many languages - hence reusability.